# 縦画面方向の状態のiPhoneで横画面比率の端末カメラを起動したい

Tags: ios, unity2d

Unityで開発しております。
iPhone端末を縦画面にしている状態で端末カメラは横方向の比率での撮影を行いたいと思っています。
WebCamTextureで端末カメラの撮影した映像を表示、それを録画するように対応しておりますが、
縦方向で撮影しているため9:16の比率の撮影になってしまいます。
画面方向設定をLandscapeLeft、LandscapeRightをtrueにして90度傾けて無理やり縦方向の端末向きでも横方向の比率の撮影を出来る用にしましたが、同画面内でモバイルキーボードを使用した文字列入力も行いたく、キーボードが横から表示されてしまう状態です。
端末を回転させずに縦方向の状態で16:9の比率の端末カメラ映像の取得方法が知りたいです。
もしくはモバイルキーボードの表示で横画面設定でも縦方向のキーボード表示方法が知りたいです。